# checkbox update to mongo is sometime work and sometime won't work

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My code sometime work and some time won't work

Mongo didn't update sometimes...

But his code is work perfact

What am i do wrong?

Here is my code

http://checkboxploblem.meteor.com

https://github.com/codepawn/practice_makes_perfect/tree/master/checkbox_mongo

origin is

https://github.com/EventedMind/class-build-a-multi-page-app-with-iron-meteor-6737880d

Comment: Please add the code in the question. If the link dies, the question dies with it.

Comment: I know but the link is onething is Github and onething is Native meteor link
So there is no worry to block the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your event within the 'home.coffee' file:

```
Template.Home.events
    'click [name=isDone]': (e, tmpl) ->
    id = @_id
    isDone = tmpl.find('input[name=isDone]').checked
    Todos.update {_id: id},
        $set:
            isDone: isDone
```

You are assigning the first checkbox value to the variable isDone.  Thus, if you check the first input box, that is what gets applied to every subsequent task.

You can get around this by retrieving the value of the checkbox from the event object. ie. `e.currentTarget.checked`

Another alternative is use a unique id for each checkbox and retrieve the value using that id

Comment: It's work perfect now
Thank you so much!! phunktrain
You are a best :)